# Using awk or other command to aggregate and process duplicates

Tags: bash, awk, aggregate

I have this task. A magazine article covers various themes. We assign a numeric value to reflect the strength of relationship (link) between a particular theme and article. Reformat the raw data to a more convenient presentation as follows.

```
INPUT DATA (tab-separated)

Theme  Article  Link_strength
A      aaa      2
A      bbb      8
B      bbb      7
C      aaa      3      

OUTPUT DATA

Article Theme_A Theme_B Theme_C
aaa     2       0       3
bbb     8       7       0
```

I tried R, but data size is a problem
So, I need figured out awk command might help. But how do it?

Comment: are there more Themes or Articles?

Comment: How is data size a problem for R, but awk is more suited?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
awk -f format.awk input.txt
```

where `input.txt` is your input data file, and `format.awk` is

```
BEGIN {
    OFS="\t"
}
NR > 3 {
    themes[$1]++
    ka[$2]++
    art[$2,$1]=$3
}

END {
    printf "%s%s", "Article",OFS
    for (j in themes) {
        printf "Theme_%s%s", j, OFS
    }
    printf "\n"
    for (i in ka) {
        printf "%s%s", i, OFS
        for (j in themes) {
            printf "%d%s", art[i,j],OFS
        }
        printf "\n"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution in R:

```
library(reshape)
cast(df,Article ~ Theme,fill=0)
```

Output

```
  Article A B C
1     aaa 2 0 3
2     bbb 8 7 0
```

Same thing using `reshape2` instead:

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df,Article ~ Theme,value.var='Link_strength',fill=0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution in R too. I will make a use of it later.